# Probability on counting principles

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Adam celebrates his birthday next month. He intends to send an invitation letter to each of his 10 friends to attend the birthday party. In how many ways can the invited friends receive the invitation letters if Adam has 3 helpers who can each deliver the letters to any of the invited friends?

Comment: Welcome at math.SE. So every for every letter there are $3$ possibilities to reach the friend?...Btw, make it your custom not to use capitals in your title. That associates with shouting and is not appreciated on this site.

Comment: Does a specific way depend on the order in which the friends receive their invitations (I assume not) or on the helper who delivers the letter?

Answer (score 1):

_  _  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  <10 people who are receiving invites>

^ place a 3 in each space representing 3 different types of invites possible for each person.

3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3

3^{10} would be the result.

59,049 possibilities